# Is $A$ compact and connected

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

> Let $\Bbb R$ be considered with usual topology.
>
> Consider  $A=\{x\in \Bbb R:\text{integral part of $x$ is even}\}$ .Show that $A$ is not  connected and not compact.

**EDITS**:
$A$ is disconnected as $A=((-\infty ,1)\cap A)\cup ((1,\infty )\cap A)$.

$A$ is unbounded since the set of even integers is a subset of $A$. So $A$ is not compact.

Is it correct?

Comment: Hint: Draw a picture of $A$. What numbers have integral part $0$, $2$, $4$, $-2$, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RE:**

> Will you please give some hints? Please don't post a full solution.

If you are discussing $\mathbb{R}$ with the "usual topology," then recall that being **compact** is equivalent to being **closed** and **bounded**. Is your set $A$, for example, **bounded**? (Why or why not?)

To show $A$ is *not* connected, the typical route is to find a **separation** using disjoint open sets $S, T \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $S \cup T = A$. Can you find such a **separation**?

Comment: $A$ is unbounded since the set of even integers is a subset of $A$.

Comment: $A$ is disconnected as $A=((-\infty ,1)\cap A)\cup ((1,\infty )\cap A)$

Comment: @BenStokes Yes & yes.